# Sections of a Vector Bundle and Equivariant Maps on the Frame Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

Throughout we work in the smooth setting.

Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a rank $k$ real vector bundle and $F(E)\to M$ denote the corresponding frame bundle.

I am trying to understand the following statement, which is taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)) wikipedia article, under the heading "Relation to Principal and Ehresmann Connections."

> The sections of $E$ are in one to one correspondence with the equivariant maps $F(E)\to \mathbf R^k$. (This can be seen by considering the pullback of $E$ over $F(E)\to M$, which is a trivial bundle isomorphic to $F(E)\times \mathbf R^k$).

I don't see how the correspondence comes about, and especially how the triviality of the pullback bundle gives it. What I can see is that if we have a section $\sigma$ of $E$, then we can define a map $F(E)\to \mathbf R^k$ which sends $(p, T)\in FE_p$ to $T^{-1}(\sigma(p))$. But I am unable to get a map in the reverse direction.

Can somebody please help, especially elucidating as to how the triviality of the pullback comes to our rescue.

Comment: Given the equivariant map $\Phi\colon F(E)\to\Bbb R^k$, just set $\sigma= T\Phi(T)$. (The equivariance, in particular, means that $\Phi(T\cdot g) = g^{-1}\Phi(T)$.)

Comment: Thank you. Can you also please comment how the triviality of the pullback bundle helps us see this.

Comment: Well, what gives the trivialization of the pullback bundle? If $p\colon F(E)\to M$ is the projection, we get a global basis of sections of $p^*E$ by taking the frame vectors. That's what underlies the definition I gave, since we're just using the coordinates of $\Phi(T)$ as coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed proof is given in section 10.12 of the wonderful book Natural Operations in Differential Geometry by Kolar, Michor, and Slovak, which you can find for free on Peter Michor's website [here](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/kmsbookh.pdf).

Here is a screenshot for those who don't feel like clicking the link:
[image]